# Modify Local Group Policy automatically

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, group-policy

I need to apply Group Policy settings in the Local Group Policy object.

Creating a domain level GPO is not an option because many of the computers are not member of the AD domain, because these belong to our clients in a SaaS relationship.

Is there a way to change Local Group Policy settings by command line or by importing a file ? This would avoid me to edit the local group policy on each client using MMC.

The clients are both running Windows 7 and Windows XP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could say that whoever architected your SAAS thing definitely should have had more experience before doing something like this.

Group olicy is all registry base - the template files for the editor tell you where the keys are, so going in and decoding that and doing the registry entries yourself is an option (ok, with SOME Exceptions that are outside the registry, but those are qute view....).

If you would be more specific we could possibly help you better - maybe someone even does part of your job and finds the registry keys.

Comment: I kept the question general to get a general answer. Thanks for the hint to the template files. 
Yes, I think RemoteApp is not a good solution for SaaS. It really seems not reliable enough.